# Subprocess with Python 3.8 and Linux Bash

Tags: bash, python3

I have Python script which reads files names from oldFiles.txt, iterate through files names which are files in a Linux directory, then update the files names using string.replace and finally run a subprocess to find those files (let's say in home directory to make the explanation and demo easier) and change their names using  `subprocess.run(['mv', 'oldfile', 'newfile')]`

Let's suppose I have files names with string "jane" and I want to replace it with "jdoe", a file's name example would be: abcd_jane.csv

The sys.argv[1] is the argument which will be passed like the follow `./changeJane.py oldFiles.txt`

I am using those empty files for local training, their names are saved in oldFiles.txt  `sdafsdfs_jane.doc 12fgdf-jane.csv files_jane.txt` each file's name is saved in one line.

Iterating and updating files names in oldFiles.txt is ok but I still couldn't figure out how to run the subprocess to achieve my goal like described above. This is what I came in, thank you very much. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Actual output `mv: cannot stat '/home/user/sdafsdfs_jane.doc 12fgdf-jane.csv files_jane.tx': No such file or directory`  From the output I can understand that maybe the path is getting attached only to the first newName and not to the rest of files names or it could be bash is reading all files names as one file name but I still don't know how to solve it.

PS: I am not showing my username and I am replacing it with `user`. So please change it into your current username.

PS: I am forced to use sys and subprocess modules, and also forced to apply all the mentioned details, its a homework assessment.

Thank you very much for your support and your comprehension.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import subprocess
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for name in f.readlines():
        newName = name.strip()
        lastName = newName.replace("jane", "jdoe")
        subprocess.run(["mv", "/home/user/"+newName, "/home/user/"+lastName])
```

**UPDATE**

I modified the script to return list so I can flawlessly iterate through items, actually the script is successfully applied on the first file name only while still 2 others, any idea please? Thank you very much.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import subprocess
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    content1 = f.readlines()
    content2 = [x.strip() for x in content1]
    content3 = [item.replace("jane", "jdoe") for item in content2]
    for x in content2:
      for i in content3:
        subprocess.run(['mv', '/home/ninja-coder/'+x, '/home/ninja-coder/'+i])
```

Comment: What if you use `os.rename` instead?

Comment: I am forced to use sys and subprocess modules only and to follow only the logic I described. Regards.

Comment: So, it is a homework exercise, we should not give you the answer :) but 2 tips: try to debug your script using simple `print()` to know what exactly is being sent to the mv command; and review `mv` command man to understand what it is expecting as arguments.

Comment: Every line is successfully tested even the subprocess.run and I am not asking for solution, I am asking for hints. You could see that I built everything, still only this very annoying bug!

Comment: What if you `print(name)` right after the `for name in f.readlines()`? What is the output?

Comment: It seems to me that the name is actually some files combines. This is the error you get when you try to move one file called '/home/user/sdafsdfs_jane.doc 12fgdf-jane.csv files_jane.tx'. and it doesn't exist.

Comment: There is an escaping line after each file's name. but the strip() function is already deleting this escaping line, so explain more please what do you mean

Comment: @Whack yes I already noticed that but how to solve it ??

Comment: Maybe you need to change the way you are iterating lines. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: the main question is: how to pass multiple files names as variable using `mv`  with `subprocess.run`

Comment: Using `mv`, you can not move multiple files to multiple file destinations: "When multiple files or directories are given as a SOURCE, the DESTINATION must be a directory. In this case, the SOURCE files are moved to the target directory." - https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-move-files-in-linux-with-mv-command/#how-to-use-the-mv-command

Comment: Well I think that readlines reads all lines at once, which probably just returns one string, then when you loop through the string, you only have one iteration, because its one string. Its probably easiest to change the way you read from the file. You could read one line with f.readline() and then move that file to its new destination. When f.readline() returns an emty string, then you at the end of the file.

Comment: @Jonatã I did what you told me but its same output `#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import subprocess
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]

    for i in content:
      newName = i.replace("jane", "jdoe")
      subprocess.run(["mv", "/home/user/"+i, "/home/user/"+newName])`          output `mv: cannot stat '/home/ninja-coder/12fgdf-jane.csv': No such file or directory`

Comment: Does `/home/ninja-coder/12fgdf-jane.csv` exists?

Comment: yess for sure, all files are in home directory. Trsut me everything is ok. if you try the same on your comp you will find same bug

Comment: I came to this script for now  `import sys
import subprocess
with open('sub1.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    for i in content:
      finalList = []
      newName = i.replace("jane", "jdoe")
      finalList.append(newName)
      for x in finalList:
        print('/home/user/'+ x)`

Comment: I am sure now I have to save old files names and new files names in different lists so I can iterate through them one by one to successfully run subprocess.run mv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks to @Jonatã and @HackLab for their hints. After several debugging I solved this very annoying assessment but I learned lots of things, again, one of the crucial success's secrets is **PRACTICE** , here is the final code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import subprocess
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    content1 = f.readlines()
    content2 = [x.strip() for x in content1]
    content3 = [item.replace("jane", "jdoe") for item in content2]
    res = dict(zip(content2, content3))
    for key, value in res.items():
        subprocess.run(['mv', '/home/ninja-coder/'+key, '/home/ninja-coder/'+value])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258325) is confusing and difficult to understand. Here is a simpler version:

```
import sys
import subprocess

file = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in file:
        source = line.strip()
        dest = line.replace("jane", "jdoe")
        subprocess.run(['mv', '<homedirectorypath>'+source, '<homedirectorypath>'+dest])
file.close()
```